Equivalent characterisation of the space $L^p_{\operatorname{loc}}(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is a non-empty open subset of $\mathbb R^n$?
Consider the euclidian space $\mathbb R^n$, where $n \in \mathbb N$ is an arbitrary integer, equipped with the usual Lebesgue measure. Moreover, let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ denote an arbitrary non-empty open set.
In most textbooks, the space $L^p_{\operatorname{loc}}(\Omega)$ is defined as follows:
Definition. Given $1 \leqslant p < \infty$, the space $L^p_{\operatorname{loc}}(\Omega)$ consists of all Lebesgue measurable functions $f : \Omega \to \mathbb R$ that satisfy
$$ \int_K |f(x)|^p \, dx < \infty, $$
for every compact set $K \subset \Omega$.
Now, the following equivalent characterisation of $L^p_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R^n)$ is well known:
$$ \tag{1} f \in L^p_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R^n) \iff f \, \chi_B \in L^p(\mathbb R^n), \quad \text{ for every ball } B \subset \mathbb R^n. $$
A simple proof. Suppose firstly that $f \in L^p_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R^n)$ and consider an arbitrary ball $B \subset \mathbb R^n$. Clearly, $\overline B$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and it contains $B$. Consequently, we obtain
$$ \int_{\mathbb R^n} |f(x)|^p \, \chi_B(x) \, dx \leqslant \int_{\overline B} |f(x)|^p \, dx < \infty, $$
where the last inequality follows from the hypothesis $f \in L^p_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R^n)$.
On the other hand, suppose now that $f \, \chi_B \in L^p(\mathbb R^n)$, for every ball $B \subset \mathbb R^n$ and consider an arbitrary compact set $K \subset \mathbb R^n$. It is well known that there exists $R > 0$ such that $K \subset B(0,R)$. Therefore, it follows that
$$ \int_K |f(x)|^p \, dx \leqslant \int_{B(0,R)} |f(x)|^p \, dx = \int_{\mathbb R^n} |f(x)|^p \, \chi_{B(0,R)} (x) \,dx < \infty, $$
where the last inequality follows from the hypothesis $f \, \chi_B \in L^p(\mathbb R^n)$, for every ball $B \subset \mathbb R^n$.
Now comes my question.
Question. Is it possible to build the analogous of $(1)$ to $\Omega$ instead of $\mathbb R^n$? That is, is it possible to guarantee something along the lines of
$$ f \in L^p_{\text{loc}}(\Omega) \iff f \chi_B \in L^p(\Omega), \quad \text{ for every ball } B \subset \mathbb R^n \quad ? $$
Thanks for any help in advance.

I don't think your suggestion is true - see if you can think of a counterexample. I think the right analogue would be "for every ball $B$ whose closure is a subset of $\Omega$". If $K$ is a compact subset of $\Omega$, do you see why $K$ is a subset of a finite union of such balls?

@IzaakvanDongen Thanks for your comment. I understand your suggestion. I can intuitively see why the formulation I proposed might fail, altought I wasn't able to build a formal counterexample. Under my formulation, the implication $(\Rightarrow)$ might not be true (or, at least, not very easy to prove...) since we can't guarantee that $\overline B \subset \Omega$. With your suggestion, this implication is trivial to show (very similar to the proof I inserted for the case of $\Omega = \mathbb R^n$).

@IzaakvanDongen On the other hand, I can't see how to solve the converse implication. You seem to give a hint on your comment, by stating that a compact set $K \subset \Omega$ can be seen as a subset of a finite union of such balls, but I can't see why this follows. Perhaps you can give more details on this conclusion ?

For a counterexample - try a function which is in $L^p_{\text{loc}}(B(0, 1))$ but not in $L^p(B(0, 1))$. For the further details - this is a fairly straightforward compactness argument. Look for a suitable open cover of $K$ which will have a useful finite subcover..

@IzaakvanDongen Thanks for you comment once again. My topology knowledge isn't very good, I should say. After drawing a diagram, I can intuitively understand that $K$ can be covered by a finite number of balls $B$ that satisfy $\overline B \subset \Omega$, but I am having a hard time formalising this idea. Perhaps you can give me some hint regarding this ?

Ah sorry, I had assumed you had some knowledge of topology. Basically, if $K$ is
compact, then for each point $x \in K$, choose an $r_x$ such that
$\overline{B(x, r_x)} \subseteq \Omega$ (using that $\Omega$ is open). Then
${B(x, r_x) : x \in K}$ is an open cover of $K$, and hence it has a finite
subcover, and that's what we want to show. If that's not making sense I would
recommend having a look at some introductory material/exercises about
compactness.

@IzaakvanDongen Thanks for your help. Do you think we can restrict this equivalent characterisation to open balls? That is, does it hold that $$f \in L^p_{\text{loc}}(\Omega) \iff f \chi_B \in L^p(\Omega), \quad \text{ for every open ball } B \subset \overline{B} \subset \Omega \quad ? $$ This seems true for $\Omega = \mathbb R^n$ but I am not certain if we can generalise it for an arbitrary non-empty open set $\Omega$.

Yes, you can do that - the proof in my previous comment shows exactly that, in fact.

@IzaakvanDongen If you care to elaborate an answer, please do. You helped me a lot with this question.

Define $\Omega_\varepsilon:=\{x\in\Omega\,|\,\operatorname{dist}(x,\Omega^c)\geq\varepsilon,\text{ and }|x|\leq\varepsilon^{-1}\}$. You can verify that $\Omega_\varepsilon$ is compact, and it holds
$$ f\in L^p_{\operatorname{loc}}(\Omega)\iff f\chi_{\Omega_{\varepsilon}}\in L^p(\Omega) \quad\forall\varepsilon >0. $$
This is one natural generalization of what you wrote for $\Omega=\mathbb R^n$.
You can rewrite this condition in a way that resembles more your original characterization:
$$ f\in L^p_{\operatorname{loc}}(\Omega)\iff f\chi_{\widetilde\Omega_{\varepsilon}\cap B}\in L^p(\Omega) \quad\forall\varepsilon >0 \text{ and for every ball }B\subset\mathbb R^n, $$
where $\widetilde\Omega_\varepsilon:=\{x\in\Omega\,|\,\operatorname{dist}(x,\Omega^c)\geq\varepsilon\}.$
Actually it is enough to verify the above conditions just for $\varepsilon^{-1}\in\mathbb N$.

As already suggested in the comments, considering only balls does not work. For example, for $n=1$, consider $\Omega=(0,\infty)$. You can verify that the function
$$ f(x)=e^{e^{e^{e^{1/x}}}} $$
belongs to $L^p_{loc}(\Omega)$ for all $p\in[1,\infty]$, but it blows up quite dramatically at $x=0$, so that for example
$$ \|f\chi_B\|_{L^p(\Omega)}^p=\int_{\Omega}|f(x)\chi_B|^pdx=\int_{\Omega\cap B}|f(x)|^pdx=\infty $$
whenever the ball $B$ contains a neighbourhood of $x=0$, for any $0<p<\infty$.
